# Integer Variable Declaration in a Function in r

Tags: r, function, variables, local, variable-declaration

I wrote a function which takes two integers variable(x,y) to define "id" array, however to get the correct output I had to change my variables (x and y like x<-... and y<-....) in the console.

```
test2 <- function(s,id = x:y){ ....
```

How can I change my variables to have a function which user could use just entering any two integers s/he wants like:

```
test2("char",10:20) without declaring x<-10 and y<-20
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function to take two integers, x and y, make it have two parameters x and y. Create `id` within it:

```
test2=function(s, x, y){
  id=x:y
  return(id) # or whatever you return
 }
```

then you call it with:

```
test2("char",10,20)
```

Comment: ,No I want my function to take an array but I couldn't figure out how to construct it in the function and then call it from the console

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If a function "takes an array" it doesn't "construct it in the function". Its just **there** in the function already, without construction. If you want to know what the limits of your array are then its just `x=min(id)` and `y=max(id)` in your function.